# Conditional format based on match in another sheet with additional rule

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am building an RSVP list in excel and need to figure out how to conditional format based on matching the name in another sheet and whether that name is listed as attending or not.

I have two sheets: Guest List (Sheet1) and RSVP List (Sheet2). On Sheet1 I would like to format it so it will highlight a cell red or green, if it matches with a guest name listed in Sheet2, based on if column E in Sheet2 says Y or N.

I am familiar with conditional formatting in the same sheet and have tried researching similar scenarios for different sheets but have not been able to apply them.

Comment: Sounds doable using `XLOOKUP`, `INDEX/MATCH`, `COUNTIFS`, or `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: Can you show us what it is you tried?

Comment: @BigBen how would I use those together?

Comment: You'd use one of them, together with `IF`.

Comment: This is doable, but my recommendation is to add a helper column in the Guest List.  Say for example, column H has a formula using VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP that may be "Y" if they RSVP yes, "N" if they RSVP "No" and "" if there as no match in the RSVP list yet.  Then do a far simpler conditional format function based on the value in column H.  The reason I prefer this is that diagnosing complex formula problems like circular references is very hard in conditional format formulas.  Conditional format formulas are a leading cause of sheet corruption so I always avoid complex formulas in conditions....

Comment: The point is I put the more complicated logic in a cell formula where it belongs, and only put the most simplified logic possible in the formatting condition.